# What is ruby's StringIO class really?

Tags: ruby, io

I think I understand `StringIO` somewhat as being similar to Java's `StringBuffer` class, but I don't really understand it fully. How would you define it and its purpose/possible uses in Ruby? Just hoping to clear up my confusion.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

no, [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/index.html) is more similar to [StringReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)/[StringWriter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) than [StringBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

In Java [StringBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) is the **mutable** version of String (since String is **immutable**).

[StringReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)/StringWriter are handy classes meant to be used when you want to fake file access . You can read/write in a [String](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) with the same stream-oriented interface of Reader/Writer: **it is immensely useful in unit testing**.

Comment: Thanks. That cleared it up for me. I would upvote your answer, but I need more rep :)