# What are the advantages to using StringIO in Ruby as opposed to String?

Tags: ruby, string, stringio

When is it considered proper to use Ruby's StringIO as opposed to just using String?

I think I understand the fundamental difference between them as highlighted by "[What is ruby's StringIO class really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211461/what-is-rubys-stringio-class-really)", that StringIO enables one to read and write from/to a String in a stream-oriented manner. But what does this mean practically?

What is a good example of a practical use for using StringIO when simply using String wouldn't really cut it?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Basically, it makes a string look like an IO object, hence the name StringIO.

The [StringIO](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) class has `read` and `write` methods, so it can be passed to parts of your code that were designed to read and write from files or sockets.  It's nice if you have a string and you want it to look like a file for the purposes of testing your file code.

```ruby
def foo_writer(file)
  file.write "foo"
end

def test_foo_writer
  s = StringIO.new
  foo_writer(s)
  raise 'fail' unless s.string == 'foo'
end
```

Comment: Interesting. Are there any advantages (with regard to memory usage) in using StringIO as opposed to String?

Comment: Probably not.  If you look at the source code it looks like it just keeps a reference to a String object internally, so it will use slightly more memory than a normal string: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/stringio/stringio.c

Comment: While there isn't a memory advantage if you are using `StringIO`, if you design your functions for IO objects you can do things such as read from a file, and otherwise pipe operations together.  So a function that takes an IO object can use less memory if it is used with an appropriate class.  So, this lets you operate on a String or a possibly more efficient IO object in the same way.

Comment: Keep in mind a `StringIO` doesn't look _exactly_ like a `File`.  One "gotcha" i just ran into -- `File.size(StringIO.new('foo')) #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of StringIO into String`

Answer (score 32):

I really like StringIO for the use-case of appending text line-by-line without having to use `"\n"` over and over again. For example, instead of this:

```
s = ''
s << "\n" << "some text on a new line"
s << "\nthis is pretty awkward"
s = "#{s}\neven more ugly!"
```

I can do this

```
s = StringIO.open do |s|
  s.puts 'adding newlines with puts is easy...'
  s.puts 'and simple'
  s.string
end
```

Which is much cleaner. It isn't necessary to use the block form of `String.IO`, you can create an object like so: `s = StringIO.new` but regardless, make sure to keep in mind the actual string is accessed via the `StringIO#string` method.

Comment: I usually use `Array#<<` and then `Array#join` for this kind of thing, though using `StringIO` is a great technique.

Comment: @jc00ke So did I actually. Now that I'm more familiar with Ruby though, my habits result in code favoring the **reader**... To illsutrate what I mean, consider the following: To the coder, using `Array` like you describe is convenient to *write* in, sure, but when *reading* code, the class name `StringIO` is a **far** better indicator of purpose. Not to mention `Array` is a fundamentally different data structure. Also, the neccessity of using `Array#join` incurs excess code 'baggage', and worse, complexity! For instance, it's argument is set by default to a global which is subject to change.

Comment: I love this, I'm stealing it. Right now.